# Can I see the full list of hot questions somewhere?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I understand that there is a pool of hot questions and with every refresh of the browser I am presented with a selection of those questions.

Is there a place where I can see the full list of current hot questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by clicking on the *Hot Network Questions* header, leading you to https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot, a list of the current 100 hot questions.